# Laravel: Search for date, ignoring time portion

Tags: php, laravel-4

How can I search for a `created_at` date, ignoring the time of day?

I'm doing it like this now, but it feels like a bit of a hack:

```
$searchDate = strtotime($search);
if($searchDate !== false) {
    $q->orWhere(DB::raw('DATE(`created_at`)'), Carbon::createFromTimestamp($searchDate)->toDateString());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is one way to do it:

```
$search_date = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($searchDate)->toDateString();

$q->where('created_at','LIKE', $search_date . '%')->get();
```

or you can writenit like this,

```
$search_date = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($searchDate)->toDateString();

$q->orWhereRaw('DATE(created_at) = ?'), array($search_date));
```